# Linux kernel crashes when inserting module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have been working on obstacle detection using ultrasonic sensor. The plan was to compare the response times in user space and as a loadable kernel module.
The user space program works fine. But when I insert the LKM the kernel freezes . I think its because of the while loop but dont know how to deal with it.  Could someone let me know the problem?

Thank you in advance.

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/time.h>
#include<linux/timer.h>
#include<linux/jiffies.h>
#include<linux/delay.h>
#include<linux/gpio.h>
#include<asm/div64.h>
# define LED 21
# define TRIG 11
# define ECHO 8

static int ultra_init(void){
    int ret=0,flag;
    unsigned long long delta, obj_time_start,distance ;
    unsigned long long speed=34;
    struct timeval start,end;
    //s64 delta;


    printk(KERN_ALERT "Module loaded");
    ret=gpio_request_one(TRIG,GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW,"write_pin");      

    if(ret)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Pin %d could not be assigned",ret);          //Priniting message in log file
        flag=1;
    }

    ret=gpio_request_one(LED,GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW,"write_pin");
    if(ret)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Pin %d could not be assigned",ret);          //Priniting message in log file
        flag=1;
    }

    ret=gpio_request_one(ECHO,GPIOF_IN,"read_pin");                                 //Defining GPIO 4 as an input
    if(ret)
        {
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Pin %d could not be assigned",ret);
        flag=1;
        }
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<5;i++){
            gpio_set_value(LED,0);
        gpio_set_value(TRIG,0);
        gpio_set_value(ECHO,0);
        udelay(200);
        gpio_set_value(TRIG,1);
        udelay(10) ;// us
        gpio_set_value(TRIG,0);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "measuring the distance......");
        printk(KERN_ALERT " ECHO STATE %d",gpio_get_value(ECHO)); 
        udelay(300);
        udelay(300);
        udelay(300);
        udelay(300);
        udelay(300);






        while(gpio_get_value(ECHO)==0){

        do_gettimeofday(&start);

        }   


        while(gpio_get_value(ECHO)==1){

        printk(KERN_ALERT "ECHO 1");
        do_gettimeofday(&end);}


    obj_time_start=ktime_to_ns(ktime_get()); // Response time
    //delta=ktime_to_ns(ktime_sub(end,start)); //ns

    delta=(end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000.0;

    delta+=(end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)/1000.0;
    //long long num=delta*17;
    //printk(KERN_ALERT "Distance calculated is %llu cm \n ", delta);
    do_div(speed,2000000);
    printk(KERN_ALERT " %llu ",speed);

    //distance=delta*0.000017; //do_div((delta*17),1000000);
    //printk(KERN_ALERT "Distance calculated is %llu cm \n ", distance);




}





}
static void ultra_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Good byee");
    gpio_set_value(LED,0);
    gpio_free(LED);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

module_init(ultra_init);

module_exit(ultra_exit);
```

Comment: Init functions of kernel module are not meant to be perform everything of the code logic! As the name suggests just do some initializations in init routine, do not write the complete logic. Your while loop is causing the kernel to wait thus result in a freeze. Instead look into gpio interrupts, level triggered in your case.

Comment: Do you know the difference between hardware GPIO lines and Linux abstraction of them? Seems not. Poking some arbitrary GPIOs might even brick a device for ever.